Grafana Cloud sum by use string instead of int
On Grafana Cloud, I'm trying to create a graph which retrieve a field "metric" from logs, to display this by range of 1 hour. This seems very easy but the sumby doesn't seems to understand the field as int.
This is my query : sum by(metric) (rate({filename="/var/log/sms-meeting/combined.log"} |= 'production' | json | metric >= 0 [1h]))
And this is how it display:

As you can see, it seems to understand "metric" as a string field and not a number which can be summed. After many hours searching on Google I tried to convert metric to integer (even if it's already integer) by using transformation tab, but this is not available on cloud.
Do you have any idea ?
EDIT:
I've tried with unwrap but there nos significant changes:


You are looking for unwrap step.

@markalex thanks for your help. I'm probably wrong, but it's doesn't seems to help me. I've updated the original post

You shouldn't be using rate. Otherwise you are "rating" your value, and I suspect you want to sum them up. See this answer, it has somewhat similar approach.

If linked answer also answers your question, and there is no significant difference for later users, consider closing this question as a duplicate. And if you see significant difference, please feel free to provide a self-answer.

You're right. Working with sum over time without rate instead of sum if much better ! But it seems having an inconsistency somewhere... I'm really new with it but, metric should be understand as a value. Which mean evolution should be visible insn't it ? Actually it seems to be ingest as a small part of the whole log, so each log is different. My graph print points instead of a line representing the evolution of metric. Even if graph style if line. I don't know if it's possible with logs.

As far as I can tell, your screenshots are from explore page. Don't think there is much to configure there. I guess, you'll have more chances to configure stuff in the actual panel.
